# Unable to cross-compile for mips

Tags: c, linux, mips, cross-compiling

I tried to cross compile the simple hello.c using mips cross compiler which throws me error.

Below is the error

```
satya@satya-dev:~/Test/kernel/check$ make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mips-buildroot-linux-uclib-
make -C /opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin/ M=/home/satya/Test/kernel/check modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin'
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My Makefile is:

```
obj-m := hello.o
#KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/
KDIR := /opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin/
#PWD = $(shell pwd)

all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

I added the compiler path to /bin also

```
satya@satya-dev:~/Test/kernel/check$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL:/opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin
```

Even compiler works fine without makefile

```
satya@satya-dev:~/Test/kernel/check$ /opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin/mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc in.c -o temp
satya@satya-dev:~/Test/kernel/check$ ll
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satya satya 1135 Aug 10 05:06 hello.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satya satya    0 Aug 10 06:29 Module.symvers
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satya satya   52 Aug 10 07:48 modules.order
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satya satya   66 Aug 10 07:59 in.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 satya satya  281 Aug 10 08:30 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 satya satya 5604 Aug 10 09:37 temp
```

I know I am doing some vague mistake, but I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: `KDIR` is a path to part of the kernel sources, not the bin directory of a cross compiler. You need something more like this: https://blukat29.github.io/2017/12/cross-compile-arm-kernel-module/

Comment: Your makefile targets don't call your gcc to compile anything, and don't mention hello.c - they just run `make` in KDIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I am doing some vague mistake, but I couldn't figure it out.
>   Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

No, it's no "vague mistake".  Your Makefile has valid *form*, but the contents are pretty much non-sensical.

In your command-line `make` invocation, you do not name a target, so `make` chooses the default (first) one in your Makefile, 'all'.  This is probably what you want, as far as it goes.

The recipe for target 'all' contains only one command:

> ```
>        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules
> ```

This runs a sub-`make` in directory `$(KDIR)`, which is surprising because it does not look like the value set for `KDIR` is part of the project you are trying to build.

The sub-`make` is asked to build a target named 'modules', and the error message indicates that `make` does not have any rule for how to do so.  Probably it does not see a makefile (under any of the names it recognizes) in the build directory, but if it does see one, then it does not contain a rule for that target.  I note that the `Makefile` you present has no rule for such a target, either, so I have no idea where that comes from.

> Even compiler works fine without makefile

Well that's good news, at least.

The key to cross-compiling is to use the correct toolchain for the purpose.  You can do this in several ways, but most of them start with defining some standard make variables appropriately.  For example:

```
tooldir = /opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin
CC = $(tooldir)/mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc
LD = $(CC)
```

The `CC` variable names the C compiler, and the `LD` variable names the linker.  There are other variables you might want or need to set, too, such as `CFLAGS` for any C compiler flags you want to use, and `LDFLAGS` for any linker flags.

There are several ways you could go from there, but the very simplest would be to name the default target "hello" instead of "all":

```
hello:
```

And that's probably all you need to build the "hello" program specifically.

Comment: I went to the directory "/opt/toolchains/crosstools-mips-gcc-5.3-linux-4.1-uclibc-1.0.12-binutils-2.25-NPTL/usr/bin". Here  I have cross compiler like this

$ ll | grep mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 501 501      17 May  4  2017 mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc -> toolchain-wrapper
But I dont have any make file. How can I proceed further

Comment: No, @satyaGolladi, the whole point is that you *shouldn't* go to that directory.  It contains tools that you must *use*, but you don't want to perform the build there.  I already gave you a complete or nearly complete example of how to write a simple Makefile for building your "hello" program.

Comment: John, in my new make file with what I should replace the below line with?
hello:
        $(KDIR) -C $(CC) M=$(shell pwd) module


Note: I am new to driver development, please bear with me

Comment: @satyaGolladi, for building a program named "hello" from  a single source file named "hello.c", you can replace that line with nothing.  A zero-line recipe.  Just name the default target "hello", and set the variables I described in the answer.  I meant you to take "that's probably all you need to build the "hello" program specifically" quite literally.